# rand () for c++ with variables

Tags: c++, srand, random

```
int userHP = 100;
int enemyHP = rand() % ((userHP - 50) - (userHP - 75)) + 1;
```

okay, for some reason this doesnt seem to work right, im trying to get 50 -25 hp for enemys.

also id rather it be a percentage... like

```
int enemyHP = rand() % ((userHP / 50%) - (userHP / 75%)) + 1;
```

but id like to stick with integers and not mess with floats or doubles... can someone help me?

Comment: Why don't you want to mess with floats or doubles?

Comment: Do not forget to accept an answer in order to say thanks to who answered you...

Comment: because i dont know how to use doubles and floats would just make things complicated. i just want integers. no decimals. and i will, my madre stole my laptop and i dont have a real account on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform some algebra on this:

```
rand() % ((userHP - 50) - (userHP - 75)) + 1;

rand() % (userHP - 50 - userHP + 75) + 1;

rand() % (userHP - userHP - 50 + 75) + 1;

rand() % (-50 + 75) + 1;
```

...and you can quickly see what's going wrong. Why not use doubles?

Answer (score 4):

To get a Random Number in range [ Minimum , Maximum ] inclusive:

**Use this integer approximation:**

```
int RandomNumber = Minimum + rand() % (Maximum - Minimum + 1);
```

And make sure that (Maximum - Minimum ) <= RAND_MAX

**Or use this better floating one:**

```
double RandomNumber = Minimum + rand() * (double)(Maximum - Minimum) / RAND_MAX;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int randRange(int a, int b) {return a + rand() % (1+b-a);}
```

Edit: Thanatos points out in the link below that this approach can give numbers with statistically poor randomness. For game purposes it will work just fine, but do not use this for scientific or cryptographic applications! (In fact don't use rand() at all, use something like a Mersenne twister.)

Comment: See: http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx for why this may not be the best solution.

Comment: Right. But it's a very simple solution than will work fine for setting enemy HP in a game, and doesn't use floating point, as requested.