# use of rand() function to generate ascii values

Tags: c++

```
int RandInt(int a, int b){
    return (rand()%b+a);
}
```

I want to generate the random character values so i call it like this

```
char asciiValue = RandInt(65, 90);
```

but my output is not quite what i expect... am i doing something wrong?

--edit put in wrong values for randint call, my bad

Comment: What is your output, if it's not what you expect?

Comment: most of the output is ascii values, im getting numbers like 106, 102, 91 which are unknown characters

Comment: possible duplicate of [rand () for c++ with variables...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982369/rand-for-c-with-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RandInt(90, 90)` will return an integer between 90 and 179. The value 90 represents a 'Z' and you can have a value up from there.

What range are you tring to get?

Capital letters would be `RandInt(65, 26)`. Is this what you expect?

Answer (score 6):

It might be better if you modify your `RandInt(low, high)` function to return a random number between low and high, inclusive.

```
int RandInt(int low, int high) {
  return low + rand() % (high - low + 1);
}
```

This way, getting a lowercase character will be really simple:

```
const char c = RandInt('a', 'z');
```

Answer (score 2):

Rand is a random number generator with period 2 to the 32nd power to return successive pseudorandom numbers in the range from 0 to RAND_MAX.

If you are using randomize() before the rand() %b+a, then the output will be different every time you compile the code as randomize() intializes the random number generator with a random value.

And as you are passing, randint(65,90), everytime you will get a symbol as output.

What is actually done here is

1)rand()%b

Here rand() will generate a random number which is between 0 to 90 as you are passing the value of a as 90.

2)Then it will add the value of a i.e. 65 here.The value you are passing.

Then whatever the calculated value is found it will be outputed to the screen.

This will be helpful to you.